# How to read number input of unsure length?

Tags: c

I've been stuck on a problem for awhile, I need to read input from the user in the form,

```
5 1.2 2.3 3.4 4.5 5.6
```

where the first integer is the number of floats to expect, and then the floats following are the values I need to store in an array of that size. The code I have that keeps returning an error is,

```
...
int i = 0, j, k;
float value, *ptr;
// For every element in inputArr...
while (i < inputLength) {
    printf("Enter the number of values in this data set, followed by the values: ");
    // Get the int value for array creation...
    scanf("%d ", &j);
    printf("%d", j);
    // Save it for the calculations later.
    *(lengths + i) = j;
    // Create dynamic array of floats.
    *(inputArr + i) = calloc(j, sizeof(float));
    ptr = *(inputArr + i);
    // For the rest of the input read the floats and place them.
    k = 0;
    while (k < j-1) {
        scanf("%f ", &value);
        *(ptr + k) = value;
        k++;
    }
    scanf("%f\n", &value);
    *(ptr + j - 1) = value;
    i++;
}
```

This throws a segmentation fault when I enter in the input above.
Can someone help me out by telling me what I'm doing incorrectly?

Comment: You didnt say what error you are getting.

Comment: @hugomg I added it to the question now - it is a segmentation fault.

Comment: Do you know what line gives a segmentation fault? (You can run the code under a debugger to find that out)

Comment: It appears that it is the lines with the way I'm using the pointers.

Comment: Of course the segmentation fault is coming from a pointer. The thhing is that if you knw which line is causing the problem the fixing it is much much easier. (do you know how to use a debugger?)

Comment: You can track where the pointer related memory is in a debugger. You should also check the return value of `scanf` to make sure that you were able to read what you expect to read before proceeding with the data that was supposed to be read in. For example `if ( scanf("%d", &j) == 1)`...

Comment: How do you define lengths and inputArr? May be the problem is there.

Comment: @hugomg I didn't think C had a debugger! what is the easiest one to use?

Comment: @Ashalynd int *lengths; float **inputArr; InputArr is an array of arrays, all declared using only point notation.

Comment: If you meant `lengths` to be an array containing N integer values (at least it looks like that from the way you use it),then once N is known, you would do something like `lengths = (int*)calloc(N, sizeof(int));` and for inputArr it would be `inputArr = (float**)calloc(N, sizeof(float*))`;

Comment: depends on what OS/compiler you are using. IF you are on linux you can use [gdb](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~gilpin/tutorial/) - just make sure that you compile your executable with the -g flag. On windows, any decent IDE should have a GUI debugger builtin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have to include spaces and end-of-strings in your scanf calls.

```
scanf("%d", &j);
```

i/o

```
scanf("%d ", &j);

scanf("%f", &value);
```

i/o

```
scanf("%f\n", &value);
```

etc.

Comment: This fixed my problem in relation to the scanf issues I was having, it appears the segmentation fault is occurring with how I'm using the pointers. Thanks.